# What effect does the export library checkbox have on a standalone project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, android-build

I was under the impression that the export checkboxes in Eclipse's project properties "order and export" tab was only used as a convenience so that dependent Eclipse projects wouldn't have to include the same library as their parent projects.

1. Does checking the export boxes for a library in a standalone project
   have any effect at all?
2. Does building for Android behave any differently than a standard Java project?  On one of my Android projects, I get a class not found runtime error unless I check the export boxes on couple of my libraries.  How could this happen?